# How to install Utopia expert font on texlive?

Tags: fonts

I'am trying to get the utopia expert font working. I am using TeXLive 2012, installed by Mactex on OSX Lion 10.7.5.

I've renamed the adobes files `UEB.PFB` and `UERG.PFB` in `putb8x.pfb` and `putr8x.pfb`

Then, i've copied this files in `/usr/local/textlive/2012/textmf-dist/fonts/type1/adobe/utopia`  , where i founded the 4 standard fonts.

I've run then `updmap-sys` in my terminal, but with no result.

Could you please tell me where to copy the files and what command i schould use ?

As you see, i'm not very experimented whit the terminal and the file structure of TexLive. I hope you can anderstand my question,

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to add those files to the main tree, but rather to the "local" tree:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/utopia
sudo cp putb8x.pfb putr8x.pfb /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/utopia
sudo mktexlsr
```

This should be enough, because the `fourier-utopia-expert.map` file is loaded by default by `updmap`. You can, for safety, do

```
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map fourier-utopia-expert.map
```

but it shouldn't be necessary.

However, be warned that those two font files are not sufficient, because you are missing (at least) the italic and bold italic font.

Why not the main tree? Because when you'll install the forthcoming TeX Live 2013 your system won't see those fonts any more. If they are in the local tree, they'll be seen by any update of TeX Live (or MacTeX, it's the same).

Comment: Tanks a lot ! It works now. I was lost in all that files... The missig one was a small caps file (putrc8a.pfb).

Comment: It spared me a lot of time tanks again for your precise answere. Pierre